# EntityFramework CodeFirst Instantiate Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an EntityFramework object with a collection, for instance:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best practice - leaving it like this or instantiating the collection in the constructor (or something else?)  If I instantiate the collection into a default blank list like this:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Pages = new List<Page>();
    }
}
```

Then I get a DevExpress/Code Analysis warning about instantiating virtual properties in the constructor - is there any danger to doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Do not instantiate it, leave your `POCO` object as it is and let `EF` operates on it as expected.  EF will instantiate them for you. You should know that `EF` will fill the navigation property which is marked by virtual through dynamic proxy.

Comment: this works if your objects are pre-existing, but what about when you are creating your objects initially?  If every object isn't instantiated in the constructor, then you have to either instantiate all collections down the inheritance chain when creating the object manually or check to ensure that each ienumerable is not null before doing a LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

this would be a better decision:

```
private readonly IList<Page> _page;

public User(IEnumerable<Page> page)
{
    _page = new List<Page>(page);
}

public IList<Page> Page
{
    get { return _page; }
}
```

be careful about using about `ICollection<>`, `IEumerable<>` and `IList<>`, see more info [here](http://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2013/07/22/when-to-use-ienumerable-icollection-ilist-and-list/)

Comment: But I thought that EntityFramework is only compatible with ICollections?

Comment: or ISet<T> set = new HashSet<T>()